# awk: Extracting characters one by one from a string

Tags: awk, gawk

Someone often writes like this when extracting characters one by one from the beginning to the end of a string.

For example:

```c
function rev1(str,    i, ret) {
    for (i = 1; i <= length(str); i++) {
        ret = substr(str, i, 1) ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I think don't necessarily have to use the length().

```c
function rev2(str,    ch, i, ret) {
    while (ch = substr(str, ++i, 1)) {
        ret = ch ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It works, but is it wrong?

Comment: if `str` was an array, so second function will be fail

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong (assuming it's input really is a string and not an array), but the resulting code is less clear since it's relying on the condition doing a string comparison since the return from substr() is a string. At a glance I thought it'd fail if the string contained a `0` but it won't thanks to that string comparison being enforced.

Comment: I thank you. I recently came up with this little algorithm. rev1() extracts characters one by one from a "whole string". So it was irrational to get the length of the string, I thought. In our country, we usually use multi-byte characters. Thus using length () in GAWK is pretty heavy and slow.

Comment: For efficiency you wouldn't REALLY call `length(str)` in every iteration of the loop like in the code you posted, you'd call it once before the loop and set a variable as in `n = length(str); for (i=1; i<=n; i++)`. It's hard to believe calling length() would be heavy and slow given that. Since you mention you're using gawk though you could do `n=split(str,arr,""); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) ret = arr[i] ret` and so exchange both length() and substr() calls for one call to split(). idk which would be faster but you could try it.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I know.Initialization only once.If rev1() works millions times then Millions of uses of length () for millions of data would seem irrational.